# Calculated row from aggregate query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a simple aggregate query, but struggling with something.

I have a table with a status field that is either 'Complete' or 'Incomplete'.
I want the query to return three rows : the number of complete, number of incomplete, and a calculated percentage of completion.

So far I have the first two rows as

```
     SELECT Status, Count(*) as countNums FROM tblStuff GROUP BY Status
```

So this would return something like

```
 Status    Countnums
 __________         
 Complete  100
 Incomplete 100
```

And what I want is

```
 Status    Countnums      Percent
 __________         
 Complete  100             50
 Incomplete 100            50
```

OR

```
 Status    Countnums      
 __________         
 Complete  100            
 Incomplete 100           
 percentComplete     50
```

Although, I don't see how the latter would work at a row level.
This is in MS Access.

Comment: MS Access and MS SQL Server are two different database products. Is it correct that you are using MS Access and not SQL Server?

Comment: I meant to tag SQL, I guess I accidentally tagged SQLServer as well. I am just using plain access, without SQL Server backend. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your existing `GROUP BY` query as a subquery and cross join that with another subquery which returns the total count from `tblStuff`.  Use the subquery values to derive `[Percent]` in the parent query.

This worked (correct result; no syntax error) with Access 2007:

```
SELECT
    group_counts.Status,
    group_counts.countNums,
    (group_counts.countNums / total_count.total_nums * 100) AS [Percent]
FROM
    (
        SELECT Status, Count(*) AS countNums
        FROM tblStuff GROUP BY Status
    ) AS group_counts,
    (
        SELECT Count(*) AS total_nums
        FROM tblStuff
    ) AS total_count;
```

Beware that `Percent` is a reserved word.  Using it as an alias without surrounding it in square brackets threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SERVER

```
SELECT Status, Count(*) AS cnt, CAST( Count(*) as decimal) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblStuff) AS perc 
FROM tblStuff 
GROUP BY Status
```

You can even save the full count in a variable

```
DECLARE @fcnt decimal

SELECT @fcnt = COUNT(*) FROM tblStuff
SELECT Status, Count(*) AS cnt,Count(*) / @fcnt AS perc 
    FROM tblStuff 
    GROUP BY Status
```

In Access

```
SELECT tblStuff.Status, Count(*) AS cnt, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblStuff as t1) AS fcnt, [cnt]/[fcnt] AS perc
FROM [tblStuff]
GROUP BY tblStuff.Status
```

Comment: I don't think the cast operation is supported in MS ACCESS, I'm getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job just fine.

```
SELECT
   Status,
   Count(*) AS CountNums,
   Count(*) / DCount("*", "tblStuff") AS Pct
FROM
   tblStuff
GROUP BY Status
```

You could get the total count relationally, but this is really no different in performance and is possibly clearer.

Comment: Hmm, I tried replacing the brackets with parentheses and removing the period, and aliasing withut the AS, and I'm still getting syntax errors.